# How to setup Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a new ASP.NET Core project where I am trying to simply query a database and display results of the query on a page. I'm new to using ASP.NET Core and have found from researching that it would be best to use Entity Framework in order to query the database.

I was trying to follow [this guide](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-using-Entity-1464feea) in order to figure out how to connect to the database via the Entity Framework, but there is a step in the guide that references a file called  `project.json` to which the line: `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",` should be added.

The problem is that this file doesn't exist in Visual Studio 2017 projects as is confirmed in [this guide](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj) and I don't see the .csproj file anywhere in my project that the article references as the replacement for `project.json`.

Is this `.csproj` file supposed to be created after the project has already been created? What is the actual process for setting up a connection to a database via the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET Core project within Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: That guide is very old and references an old version of .Net Core that has been abandoned long ago. Try here instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning how to create a ASP.NET Core project, my teacher suggested us to follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) from the MS docs. I suggest you to follow that guide to solve your problem. In that guide says that you need to add the connection string of your database to the file `appsettings.json` that's located in your projects main folder. The connection string is like this:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

> And you add that connection string to the file `appsettings.json`, just like this:
>
> ```
> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "DB_String": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
> },
> ```
>
> Then you have to change the `ConfigureServices` method at the `Startup.cs` file in your project main folder by adding the following line:
>
> ```
> services.AddDbContext<yourContextClass>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB_String")));
> ```
>
> And then the method will seen like this:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>    {
>        services.AddDbContext<yourContextClass>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB_String")));
>        services.AddMvc();
>    }
> ```

That are the steps to configurate with ASP.NET Core 2 a database connection with Entity Framework by using the SQL Server client. For the next steps I suggest you to follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: Where does the `Biblioteca_Context` come from?

Comment: It comes frontera a example exercise that I've made... Excuse me, I  changed that...

Comment: Where is the context class supposed to be defined?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 The `Context` is supposed to be defined in another source file of your project. The `Context` class inherits from `DbContext` class, which is contained in the System.Data.Entity namespace. Here is the `DbContext` class definition at Microsoft MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: So I just need to add another class called yourContextClass (in this case) to the root of the VS project?

Comment: Yes, please see the guide that I've mentioned in the answer to get more information about the `DbContext` Class, the instantiation of that class and its importance in the project.

Answer (score 1):

**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Cn": "Server=(localdb);Database=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abcd123!"
  }
```

**DbContext**

```
public TestDbContext:DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> option) : base(option)
    {

    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
         relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Cn")));
}
```

Finally, you can work with code first approach, under your model class library.

Comment: Which file does the db context need to be created in and is that all that is needed?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 under Model folder you can create TestDbContext. this tutorial site could help you: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. It provided information on how to derive models from existing tables